# How to pass a powershell command to AWS SSM Document/Run Command using Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, terraform

I am trying to leverage the AWS-RunPowerShellScript SSM Document and pass a command through it, to run on Windows EC2 instances. I am having trouble figuring out how to pass the below Command to the Terraform.

*Command*
`powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -file "C:\aws\1-start-ebs-snapshot.ps1"`

I need to run the command on EC2 instances using below SSM document.

```
resource "aws_ssm_document" "run_powershell_cmd" {
  name          = "AWS-RunPowerShellScript"
  document_type = "Command"

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked for me:

```
resource aws_ssm_document run_powershell_cmd {
  name          = "run_powershell_cmd"
  document_type = "Command"

  content = <<DOC
  {
    "schemaVersion": "1.2",
    "description": "execute pwsh command",
    "parameters": {

    },
    "runtimeConfig": {
      "aws:runPowerShellScript": {
        "properties": [
          {
            "id": "0.aws:runPowerShellScript",
            "runCommand": ["powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -file 'C:\\aws\\1-start-ebs-snapshot.ps1'"]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
DOC
}
```